# Retriever Method Java

Tags: java, methods

I just wanted to ask what is retriever method in Java? I have been searching for it on Google but still haven't got the answers. If anyone knows, how to use it on your coding?

Comment: I have not heard of that term being used -- are you sure that you transcribed it correctly? Perhaps you meant accessor, or "getter", method?

Comment: Hmmm.... The term "getter method" is very common.

Comment: It was on my exercise questions. The question was like "Write the retriever method for each name and isMember attributes".

Comment: They are probably referring to "getter" methods, also known as "accessor" methods. For example, if you have a field called, `private String myString;` you would create a `public String getMyString() { return myString; }` getter method for it. That's all.